# Nodemon crashing after deploying Heroku App, ERROR: Invalid ELF header

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment

I am deploying a NodeJS App on Heroku, the nodemon package I have installed with it is crashing during open, can anybody fix this? Happy to clarify any of my server code for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Heroku doesn't support devDependencies. 
link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

> In order create a smaller slug size for apps, the buildpack will prune out the devDependencies from the package.json at the end of the build, so that the slug will only include the dependencies that are listed at runtime. If there is a dependency that is in the devDependencies that is needed after the prune occurs, move the dependency to dependencies, so it is not removed.